# How to convert object[] to specific type array

Tags: java

I do not think I can convert the following:

```
List<B> c = new ArrayList<B>();
c.add(***);
object[] a = c.toArray();
B[] b = (B[])a; //How to cast a back to B[]?
```

How can I achieve this in Java?

Comment: Is `B` an actual type, or a generic type parameter? What is the value of `a`? Did you mean `Object` instead of `object`? A short but complete program would really help here...

Comment: a is actualy get from List<B>'s toArray method.

Comment: `toArray()`, or `toArray(B.class)`? Again, a short but complete program would really help...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The other answers show what to do if you *really* need to convert an `Object[]` - but there's a better approach. Change your code to start with:

```
List<B> c = new ArrayList<B>();
c.add(***);
B[] b = c.toArray(new B[c.size()]);
```

Or:

```
List<B> c = new ArrayList<B>();
c.add(***);
B[] b = c.toArray(new B[0]);
```

Answer (score 4):

If every element of `a` is of type `B`, you have two options (if not, you need to explain what's going on first):

```
B[] bArray;
if(a instanceof B[]){
    // a is actually of type B[], so we'll cast it
    bArray = (B[]) a;
}else{
    // a is of type Object[], so we'll create a new array and copy the values
    bArray = Array.newInstance(B.class, a.length);
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, bArray, 0, a.length);
}
```

Also, this will only work if B is a real type, not a generic parameter!

Comment: can I do this? I am suspecting

Comment: @king_nak yeah, my bad. the version I used only makes sense if B.class isn't known at compile-time.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this through a cast. You must copy the data.

```
B[] b = new B[a.length];
for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
   b[i] = (B)a[i];
}
```

Comment: `System.arraycopy()` is a lot more efficient for copying array values

Comment: Saw that in your post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@Jon Skeet's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7498733/1427295) is correct but here is some context from the Intellij IDEA inspection info:

> There are two styles to convert a collection to an array: either using
> a pre-sized array (like c.toArray(new String[c.size()])) or using an
> empty array (like c.toArray(new String[0]).
>
> In older Java versions using pre-sized array was recommended, as the
> reflection call which is necessary to create an array of proper size
> was quite slow. However since late updates of OpenJDK 6 this call was
> intrinsified, making the performance of the empty array version the
> same and sometimes even better, compared to the pre-sized version.
> Also passing pre-sized array is dangerous for a concurrent or
> synchronized collection as a data race is possible between the size
> and toArray call which may result in extra nulls at the end of the
> array, if the collection was concurrently shrunk during the operation.